# print via the command line data of a running linux C process

Tags: c++, linux, shared-memory

The scenario is the following (no code available yet): A linux process runs forever in while(1) loop. The process is implemented in C/C++ (POSIX). The process keeps some data to a std::vector.

```
myvector.push_back("test1");
myvector.push_back("test1");
myvector.pop_back();
myvector.push_back("test1");
```

The process runs and modifies the vector. I am looking for a mechanism that will print the vector values when executing the binary with a specific command line argument.

Let's say that the process called "myprocess" and is running. I want to execute the same binary from a new shell like ./myprocess -debug and print the values of the STL container.

Any idea? What is the best mechanism to do it (ie print the memory of another process)

Comment: This is for a production system

Comment: Does this even compile? `std::vector` doesn't have a `pop()` member function.

Comment: m..Are you thinking about pipes??

Comment: There is no `C/C++ (POSIX)`. There is C (current standard is C99). There is C++ (current standard is C++11). There is POSIX (current standard is POSIX:2008). Don't mangle them into a single programming language.

Comment: You have (or will have) one process that has a populated vector, and you want to print this vector from another process? In that case you can maybe put the vector in shared memory via a custom allocator?

Comment: @cateof: How did you extend the STL with a custom member function? I smell undefined behavior.

Comment: @phresnel removed my comment to avoid this discussion since it is off topic and my lead to wrong direction. Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, you don't "print the memory of another process". What you do is send the other process a signal asking it to print out the contents of the vector.

For this, you could use a [POSIX signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29) (e.g. `SIGUSR1`).

A more flexible approach would be for the process to listen on a named pipe (or a TCP port) and accept commands over it. One such command could be to print out the contents of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

(To complete the last suggestion of @aix)

Assuming you have the source of `myprocess` and are able to enhance it, you could add some server abilities inside it.

For instance, you could make it an HTTP server (e.g. with the [Onion HTTP server library](http://www.ohloh.net/p/onionhttp)) able to understand requests. These requests could even contain some scripting language (like [lua](http://www.lua.org/)) then you'll embed an interpreter to handle them (in a separate thread, for instance). In that case, take care of synchronization issues (by e.g. locking with a mutex or a read-write lock the accessed data).

The advantage of using an HTTP protocol is that you can probe your application using a browser. (But you might need to handle sessions, authentications, etc..).

You could also use your own protocol, or RPC-XDR, Corba, etc etc.

You could also accept single requests (e.g. in Lua), on per line, thru `telnet`.

And you might put the data to be visible outside in a shared memory segment using [posix shm](http://linux.die.net/man/7/shm_overview)

In general such a specification change requires some software architectural changes

The details might not be simple...